# Issue Using webpack aliases

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, webpack

My React-Native project is getting bigger and I have some imports like this:

`import Loading from '../../../../commons/Loading';`

so I decide to use [webpack aliases](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig) to have a better importing way, so I followed the  [webpack aliases](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig) doc and I created `jsconfig.json`  file and I added

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "baseUrl": ".",
      "paths": {
        "commons/*": ["./app/commons/*"]
      }
    }
  }
```

the structure of my project.
[image]

then I changed the importing in the same file to `import Loading from 'commons/Loading';`

but it don't work and it shows me error `error: Error: Unable to resolve module commons/Loading`

Any clue what's the problem? or Maybe Solution

Answer (score 1):

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "module": "commonjs",
      "target": "es6",
      "baseUrl": "./app"      
    }
}
```

Should solve the problem.

Comment: you meant it should be like that `{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "module": "commonjs",
      "target": "es6",
      "baseUrl": "./app"  ,
      "paths": {
        "commons/*": ["./commons/*"]
      }
    }
  }`

Comment: You don't need to put anything other than I pasted.

Comment: and how should I import it ?
like this. `import Loading from 'app/commons/Loading';` if so, it didn't work for me.

Comment: import Loading from 'commons/Loading';